# Weird jquery quotes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, text-to-speech, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm writing a function that activates when you click on a prediction from bootstrap's typeahead function. This function passes a word value and the desired language to a text-to-speech function.

This text-to-speech function works properly, but I'm stuck with passing bootstrap's prediction s to this function.

The console logs "syntax error on line 1", and I believe it's because of a quotes problem in the **append** function

I hope someone here can help me to set the quotes correctly.

```
$('#search-box').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, value)
{
   console.log(value.value);
  $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" onClick="praten("value.value", "nl")">' + value.value + '\&nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />');
});
```

Comment: `'<a href="#" onClick="praten("value.value", "nl")">'  ` Escape the double quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your onclick:

```
$('#search-box').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, value) {
                console.log(value.value);
                $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" onClick="praten(&quot;value.value&quot;, &quot;nl&quot;)">' + value.value + '\
        &nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />');
            });
```

Or else use apostrophes:

```
$('#search-box').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, value)
{
   console.log(value.value);
  $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" onClick="praten(\'value.value\', \'nl\')">' + value.value + '\&nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />');
});
```

Also, if you're using jQuery, you don't need an `onclick` handler at all:

```
$('#search-box').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, value)
{
    $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" '+value.value+'\&nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />')
                    .click(function() {
                        praten(value.value, "n1");
                    });
};
```

Comment: Thx for mentioning &quot; ! this got me in the right direction :) I have solved it like this: $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" onClick="praten(&quot;'+value.value+'&quot;, &quot;nl&quot;)">' + value.value + '\
            &nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />');

Comment: See that I've used both &quot; and normal quotes